# pimpl helper ambiguous with inheritance

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I'm playing around with creating a utility class for the pimpl idiom, however I have some problem I hoped to get some help with:

This is what I've got: 
[sehe: <sup><sub>see also rev.1 here: https://gist.github.com/1379569/9f6cca5703e6195da65e34103393d901dde3b1bf</sub></sup>]

`pimpl.h`

```
template<typename T>
class pimpl
{
    template <typename> friend class pimpl;

    pimpl(const pimpl& other);
    pimpl(pimpl&& other);
    pimpl& operator=(const pimpl& other);
    pimpl& operator=(pimpl&& other);    
protected:

    ~pimpl();

    struct implementation;
    std::unique_ptr<implementation> impl_;
public:
    pimpl();

    template<typename P0>
    pimpl(P0&& p0);

    pimpl(const T& other);
    pimpl(T&& other);

    void swap(T& other);
};
```

`pimpl_impl.h`

```
// #include "pimpl.h" // TODO add header guards...

template<typename T>
pimpl<T>::pimpl() : impl_(new implementation()){}

template<typename T>
template<typename P0>
pimpl<T>::pimpl(P0&& p0) : impl_(new implementation(std::forward<P0>(p0))){}

template<typename T>
pimpl<T>::~pimpl(){}

template<typename T>
pimpl<T>::pimpl(const T& other) : impl_(new implementation(*((pimpl&)other).impl_)){}

template<typename T>
pimpl<T>::pimpl(T&& other) : impl_(std::move(((pimpl&)other).impl_)){}

template<typename T>
void pimpl<T>::swap(T& other)
{
    impl_.swap(other.impl_);
}
```

And this is how you use it:

`A.h`

```
#include "pimpl.h"

class A : public pimpl<A>
{
    A();
    A(const A& other);
    A(A&& other);
    virtual ~A();
    void foo();
};
```

`A.cpp`

```
#include "A.h"
#include "pimpl_impl.h"

template<>
struct pimpl<A>::implementation
{
     void foo()
     {
     }
};

A::A() : pimpl(){}
A::A(const A& other) : pimpl(other){}
A::A(A&& other) : pimpl(std::move(other)){}
A::~A(){}
void A::foo(){impl_->foo();}
```

This works quite well, however it quickly breaks down when you put inheritance into the picture:

```
class B : public pimpl<B>, public A
{
    ...
};

B::B() : pimpl() {} // pimpl ambiguous
```

`pimpl` has become ambiguous...

Any ideas as to how to avoid this?

Comment: Well first off, I don't see why pimpl's constructors (a great many) would have to be so overly generic? Second, [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is at play. A class has-a impl, not is-a impl IMO

Comment: Template parameter for pimpl doesn't help?

Comment: @sehe Any reason you modified/corrected the code?

Comment: @Bart: because [it wouldn't compile](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8198236/revisions) :) `@Everyone`: here is the code working compiling in a gist: https://gist.github.com/1379569

Comment: @sehe I assumed so, but I would hesitate to modify any code given by the OP.

Comment: Anything to do with [GotW #101](http://herbsutter.com/2011/11/16/gotw-101/) perhaps? There is some relevant discussion there

Comment: Everyone: If you're interested, Herb Sutter jut posted _his_ take on a generalized `pimpl idiom` for C++11: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend stuffing pimpl into a [curious base class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) because of Liskov, I don't see any real problem to make it work;

Like @Nim suggested: it all seems to pan out nicely when doing

```
class B : public pimpl<B>, public A
{
    B() : pimpl<B>() {} 
};
```

Gist updated with full sample code that works with B:

- **https://gist.github.com/1379569**
- See it live on **http://ideone.com/te49B**

B.h

```
#include "A.h"

class B : public pimpl<B>, public A
{
  public:
    B();
    B(const B& other);
    B(B&& other);
    virtual ~B();
    void bar();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "pimpl_impl.h"
#include "B.h"

template<>
struct pimpl<B>::implementation
{
     void bar()
     {
     }
};

B::B() : pimpl<B>(){}
B::B(const B& other) : pimpl<B>(other){}
B::B(B&& other) : pimpl<B>(std::move(other)){}
B::~B(){}
void B::bar(){ pimpl<B>::impl_->bar();}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Comment: @ronag: If you're interested, Herb Sutter jut posted _his_ take on a generalized `pimpl idiom` for C++11: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/